# BLOB field in database or directly in the file systeme for 1Go files?

Tags: python, django, filesystems, blob, data-warehouse

I need to store large file (around 1Go) on my data warehouse. To explain the global contexte simply : the user selects some options in a webview and sends it to the middleware. The middleware uses these informations and sends new ones to a factory. The factory creates the 1Go file. Now I need to store it on the data warehouse in order to be download later by the user.

I use the framework django for the middleware and the factory is programmed in python.

So my question is : for this size of files, is it better to store it on a blob field on a database ? Or is it better to store it directly on the file systeme ?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438486/database-blobs-vs-disk-stored-files) includes some of the pros and cons of the file system vs blobs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slowness found when base 64 image select and encode from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228496/slowness-found-when-base-64-image-select-and-encode-from-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing you blob in database using a `BinaryField` will harm the performance of your application as your querysets will have to handle a lot more data. Best practice is to store blobs in separate files and only store the file path - using `models.FilePathField()` field - in your database and serve the actual image as static file. See [this](https://www.quantifiedcode.com/knowledge-base/performance/Using%20%60BinaryField%60%20to%20store%20raw%20binary%20data/3OfSNY69) post for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I go see your solution straight ahead. I'll validate your answer tomorrow in order to see if i can get other opinions. But thanks :)